# php code causing page to not load

Tags: php, html, authentication

I am trying to integrate a simple login for my site with php. i found a script here http://www.phpfreecode.com/php-Login-system.htm got everything set up but this php code is cause the page not to load at all

```
<?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
 echo "You are logged in: $_COOKIE['user'] Enjoy.";
 } else{ 
 echo "You are not logged in. <a href='register.php'>Register here</a>";
 ?>
```

I get a server error "The website encountered an error while retrieving (my website) It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly" i have php configured on my server, i know this because i have other php files that work on the website. what am i doing wrong? also if someone knows of a better login system im open for suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: This code is fine, it must be something else

Comment: Look at the server's error log and see what the real problem is.

Comment: That code is vulnerable to sql injection, dont use it

Comment: @MarcB how do i check that i am running ubuntu server with apache2

Comment: look at the httpd.conf stuff and see where the error logs are stored, then go dig around those files.

Comment: If you're trying to use your code as you posted it, you have a `missing closing bracket`. That's why you're getting an error, `IF` that's your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with this piece of code you have suppled, is the $_COOKIE array not being seperated by curly brackets or broken out of the string.

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    echo "You are logged in: {$_COOKIE['user']} Enjoy.";
} else{
    echo "You are not logged in. <a href='register.php'>Register here</a>";
}
?>
```

or better yet:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    echo "You are logged in: ".htmlentities($_COOKIE['user'])." Enjoy.";
} else{
    echo "You are not logged in. <a href='register.php'>Register here</a>";
}
?>
```

Also that script is vulnerable to sql injection username: `whatever' OR 'X'='X` & is using the soon tobe deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: You forgot the `"i"` in `.htmlentites` - should read `.htmlentities`. Tried an `edit` but gave me an error of minimum characters. Should he want to copy/paste your code, he'll get an error.

Comment: that did the trick thank you so much too bad now im worried about the security issue side of things.. guess ill have to do some more research to find a more secure way to login

Comment: The actual script can be fixed just change the sql functions used to PDO of mysqli_* and use prepared query's.